# CSRF in a HTML App using Laravel Routes

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, laravel, phonegap-cli

I'm developing an app using the PhoneGap API but the problem is it takes over the 'View' property of Laravel.

The other problem is the index file must be .html so i'm unsure of how to secure user requests. Usually I would have the csrf meta tag in the header but in this case I am unable to save the `csrf_token()` in the meta tag as PHP can't run in the HTML file.

I was thinking maybe something like cookies would be best to secure the requests to the different routes (post/get requests) but am still quite unsure of how I would achieve this.

The general functionality of my phone application would be making use of POST and GET methods which retrieve and add data to the controllers (i.e. Signing a user up)

What are the different options I could make use of to secure my application requests using Javascript/HTML as a connection to Laravel Controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with `api_token`? Actually app requests need not to be `csrf` protected once you authenticate api requests via `api_token`. Generate an unique `api_token` for each of your user. Wrap your api routes with `api` middleware. Append this token in every api request via GET parameter / Authorization header / as an auth password.

This article might be helpful. [How touse API tokens for authentication in Laravel](https://andrew.cool/blog/64/How-to-use-API-tokens-for-authentication-in-Laravel-5-2)

Comment: Hi Mahfuzul - Is this the same as https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport ?

Comment: Also - I have a feeling this doesn't work for Laravel 5.3 as the Authenticate middleware has disappeared

Comment: Yes it's passport. For API routes middleware is `auth:api`

Comment: I suggest you describe how to implement passport to make this answer more comprehensive for others.  Thank you for your time sir!